# magento white page after config.xml overwrite via ftp

Tags: xml, magento, ftp

I was messing around with a new magento installed theme. I overwrote the config.xml file in: /mysite.com/html/app/code/local/Meigee/ThemeOptionsBlacknwhite/etc

I added 1 line to the file and overwrote it via ftp. Now the entire site is not loading (blank white page).

I tried copying over the backup config.xml file I had and it still loads a blank page.

I changed the file permissions to 666 and same deal.

Comment: Are you sure that the XML in your config file is valid ? http://www.xmlvalidation.com/
You should also check /var/report if you have error files.

Comment: I just checked on that site and it says it is valid. It is also the original file that was used and working so it must be valid.

Comment: Uploading by FTP may have changed the file owner, you should check that as well.